# Proof of Properties of Fourier series in CT

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

I feel problem in understanding the proof of Fourier series properties
1) **Time scaling**
$$b_k = \frac{1}{T}\int_{T}x(t)e^{jk\omega_0t}dt$$
a= scaling factor
$$ = \frac{a}{T}\int_{T/a}x(at)e^{jk(\omega_0a)t}dt$$
L=at
$$ = \frac{a}{T}\int_{T}x(L)e^{jk\omega_0L}\frac{dt}{a}$$
$$ = \frac{1}{T}\int_{T}x(L)e^{jk\omega_0L}dt = a_k$$ 
Q) For this I want to ask that how $T/a$ term in the integral changes $dt/a$?
2)**Multiplication**
$$x(t)y(t)= \sum^{+\infty}_{k\ =\ -\infty} a_k  e^{jk\omega_0t}dt\sum^{+\infty}_{k\ =\ -\infty} b_k  e^{jl\omega_0t}dt$$
$$ \sum^{+\infty}_{k\ =\ -\infty} \sum^{+\infty}_{l\ =\ -\infty} a_k b_le^{j(k+l)\omega_0t}$$
let m=k+l
$$ \sum^{+\infty}_{m\ =\ -\infty} [\sum^{+\infty}_{l\ =\ -\infty} a_{m-l} b_l]e^{jm\omega_0t} $$
Q) I couldn't understand this last step, why the summation changes from $k$ to only  $m$? isn't it should be $m-l$ and also is it done here to prove the multiplication property? or there are more steps? because in the Signals and Systems 2nd Edition Chapter 3, page 204 the just mentioned that $$ x(t)y(t) -> h_k= \sum^{+\infty}_{l\ =\ -\infty}a_lb_{k-l}$$

Comment: For 1) If we substitute $t' = at$, then $t = t'/a$ and $dt = dt'/a$.
For 2) Since $m$ ranges from negative to positive infinity, we can safely let $k = m - l$. This way, the exponent depends on the outer summation only.

Comment: For 1) is there any rule or property to write $dt=dt'/a$ and how T/a term in integral changes to T?

Comment: Hi Aadnan, have you studied Calculus? This is basic substitution in integration. After you substitute say $t' = t/a$ this time, you have to adjust dt and the integration limits (i.e. $dt = a dt'$ and $t = T_0$ after substitution becomes $t' = t/a = T_0/a$)...

Comment: Make sure to review [Calculus - the Substitution Rules](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Integration_techniques/Recognizing_Derivatives_and_the_Substitution_Rule)!

Comment: is this $t'=t/a$ or it should be $t'=ta$? can you be please check

Comment: $t' = t/a$ *this time*. It was on purpose. Please make sure to do the substitution by hand, and determine $dt$ and $T$ in each case (or which substitution caused it), reviewing substitution along the way, because it is basic but essential. Thanks!

Comment: @Weaam i understand the first part completely.. for 2 questions. i still have confusion why the summation is not from $m-l$ why it is from $m$. second thing, the multiplication property ends here? in the book only mentioned the term in brackets

Comment: If the summation was finite, then you would be right. The point in this substitution is that it is infinite. Since $k = m-l$, then $m = k + l$, but at $k = -\infty$, then $m = -\infty + l = -\infty$.

Comment: Ok but is this end here? because in the book the just mentioned the term in brackets the outer summation and exponential is not there

Comment: I didn't get that, would you rephrase it. (Or tell me which book you're referring to, and on what page)!

Comment: You can check now

Comment: There's got to be a dozen books titled "Signals and Systems", who's the author?

Comment: Alan Oppenheim, Alan Willsky with S Hamid Nawab

Comment: In any case, the coefficient $h_k$ gives $\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} h_m e^{jm \omega_0 t}$, can you see that?

Comment: i didnt get.. how?

Comment: Just define $h_m = \sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty} a_{m-l} b_{l}$ or $\sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty} a_{l} b_{m-l}$ and make a substitution if necessary!

Comment: OK but do you think after defining this.. does it follow the multiplication property?

Comment: If you have a specific objection/misconception, please tell so we can sort it out. But this is how multiplication of series looks like, and $h_m$ is just a way to rename $\sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{m-l}b_l$. Moreover, as we discussed, it doesn't make a difference because it is an infinite series.